# How to parse YAML MIME type in PHP

Tags: php, mime-types

Good afternoon all,

I am trying to catch data in my application which originates from a Puppet Master server (Puppet open source version 4.9).  The Puppet Server has the ability to process reports from all of it’s clients and send them over to a destination via an HTTP POST as MIME type application/x-yaml.  I have configured the Puppet Server to send data to my application server.

I see the traffic coming into the my application server from the Puppet Master Server  (via tcpdump).  I also see within my application that some POST data is arriving, however, I don’t know how to catch as parse it.  When I try to dump the $_POST data, it reads empty.  I am using Yii2 as the application framework.  Would anyone know how to catch this data and parse it for insertion into a database?

Thank you
-cs

Answer (score 0):

PHP won't parse any request types other than form-encoded or multipart, if it's a non-multipart request with only YAML PHP won't do anything with it.

You can access the raw request body using the [input stream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) `php://input`. eg:

```
use foolib/YamlParser;

$rawbody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$myobject = YamlParser($rawbody);
```

It should be noted that YAML defines some data structures that don't exactly map cleanly to native PHP types, so YMMV depending on what parser you pick. PHP does not have a built-in YAML parser.